# How to prove the following integral inequality

Tags: integration, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are integrable on $[a,b]$,$0<m\le f(x)\le M,\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$
prove:$$
\left( \int_a^b{f\left( x \right) g\left( x \right) \text{d}x} \right) ^2\le \left( \frac{M-m}{M+m} \right) ^2\int_a^b{f^2\left( x \right) \text{d}x}\int_a^b{g^2\left( x \right) \text{d}x}.
$$
The solution is only suggested by the Cauchy integral inequality, but I can't prove the problem very well.

Comment: I don't really understand. The Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality already assures a sharp inequality.

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality has equal conditions,And even if the inequality is a strict inequality, it can also be written as a non-strict inequality。